# Laravel 4/5, order by a foreign column

Tags: laravel, eloquent, query-builder

In Laravel 4/5 how can order a table results based in a field that are connected to this table by a relationship?

My case:

I have the `users` that only store the `e-mail` and `password` fields. But I have an another table called `details` that store the `name`, `birthday`, etc...

How can I get the `users` table results ordering by the `details.name`?

P.S.: Since users is a central table that have many others relations and have many items, I can't just make a inverse search like `Details::...`

Comment: Are you using Eloquent and what does the current request to get the records look like?

Comment: You must `join` the details table, there's no other way.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using join.  (Models should be named in the singular form; User; Detail)

```
$users = User::join('details', 'users.id', '=', 'details.user_id')  //'details' and 'users' is the table name; not the model name
    ->orderBy('details.name', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

If you use this query many times, you could save it in a scope in the Model.

```
class User extends \Eloquent {
    public function scopeUserDetails($query) {
        return $query->join('details', 'users.id', '=', 'details.user_id')
    }
}
```

Then call the query from your controller.

```
$users = User::userDetails()->orderBy('details.name', 'asc')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I already using this way, and it is very bad since can make conflicts when ordering columns with same name like id, etc. I was searching a more "ORM" way..